# JavaScript won't execute after meta redirect

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following code on most pages of my site.

```
<img src="img/english.png" alt="English" width="25" height="25" class="Clickable" title="View in English" onclick="document.body.className='en'" /></em><img src="img/arabic.png" alt="Arabic" width="25" height="25" class="Clickable" title="View in Arabic" onclick="document.body.className='ar'" />
```

It works with my CSS file to hide divs of each class when clicked, with English being shown as default.

CSS:

```
body.en :lang(ar) {
  display: none;

}
body.ar :lang(en) {
  display: none;

}
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="document.body.className='en'">
```

However, once the user uses my contact form, then the JavaScript will no longer function on the site.

```css
body {
 background-color: #B5E2FB;
 font-family: "Myriad Web Pro";
 text-align: center;
}
.NavBar {
 border-right-color: #999;
 border-left-color: #999;
}
a:hover {
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);
 opacity: 0.5;
}
.Footer {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/glyphish/glyphish/16/47-fuel-icon.png"/>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Fantastic Fuel | Contact</title>
</head>

<body>
<table align="center" width="1000" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="145" bgcolor="#5CA7C2"><img src="img/header.png" width="1000" height="145" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="50" bgcolor="#5CA7C2"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/home.png" alt="Home Button" width="200" height="50" border="0" class="NavBar" /></a><a href="about.html"><img src="img/about.png" alt="About Button" width="200" height="50" border="0" class="NavBar" /></a><a href="contact.html"><img src="img/contact.png" alt="Contact Button" width="200" height="50" border="0" class="NavBar" /></a><a href="faq.html"><img src="img/faq.png" alt="FAQ Button" width="200" height="50" border="0" class="NavBar" /></a><a href="products.html"><img src="img/products.png" alt="Products Button" width="200" height="50" border="0" class="NavBar" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td height="26" valign="top" bgcolor="#5CA7C2"><table width="1000" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="586">
<body>
 
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div align="left" id="main">
  
  <form id="contact-form" action="send_form_email.php" method="post">
   <h3>Get in touch</h3>
   <h4>Fill in the form below, and we'll get back to you within 24 hours.</h4>
   <form name="contactform" method="post" action="send_form_email.php">
 
<table width="450px">
 
<tr>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <label for="first_name">First Name *</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <input  type="text" name="first_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
<tr>
 
 <td valign="top"">
 
  <label for="last_name">Last Name *</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <input  type="text" name="last_name" maxlength="50" size="30">
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
<tr>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <label for="email">Email Address *</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <input  type="text" name="email" maxlength="80" size="30">
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
<tr>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <label for="telephone">Telephone Number</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <input  type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="30" size="30">
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
<tr>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <label for="comments">Comments *</label>
 
 </td>
 
 <td valign="top">
 
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6"></textarea>
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
<tr>
 
 <td colspan="2" style="text-align:center">
 
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
 
 </td>
 
</tr>
 
</table>
 
</form>
  
  </div>
 </div>
        <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="49" bgcolor="#5CA7C2"><p class="Footer">Copyright <strong>© </strong>Fantastic Fuel LLC 2015. All Rights Reserved. Produced as part of Hugh Raynor's IT BTEC.</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Any advice is appreciated.

```css
body {
 background-color: #B5E2FB;
 font-family: "Myriad Web Pro";
 text-align: center;
}
.NavBar {
 border-right-color: #999;
 border-left-color: #999;
}
a:hover {
 filter: alpha(opacity=50);
 opacity: 0.5;
}
.Footer {
 text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/png" href="http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/glyphish/glyphish/16/47-fuel-icon.png"/>
<meta HTTP-EQUIV="REFRESH" content="5; url=http://www.fantasticfuel.com">
<title>Fantastic Fuel | Contact</title>

</head>

<body>
<table align="center" width="1000" border="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="145" bgcolor="#5CA7C2"><img src="img/header.png" width="1000" height="145" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="50" bgcolor="#5CA7C2"><a href="index.html"><img src="img/home.png" alt="Home Button" width="200" height="50" border="0" class="NavBar" /></a><a href="about.html"><img src="img/about.png" alt="About Button" width="200" height="50" border="0" class="NavBar" /></a><a href="contact.html"><img src="img/contact.png" alt="Contact Button" width="200" height="50" border="0" class="NavBar" /></a><a href="faq.html"><img src="img/faq.png" alt="FAQ Button" width="200" height="50" border="0" class="NavBar" /></a><a href="products.html"><img src="img/products.png" alt="Products Button" width="200" height="50" border="0" class="NavBar" /></a></td>
  </tr>
  
  <tr>
    <td height="26" valign="top" bgcolor="#5CA7C2"><table width="1000" border="0">
      <tr>
        <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="586">
<body>
 
 <div class="wrapper">
  <div align="left" id="main">
    <p>Thanks for contacting Fantastic Fuel, your message has been recieved and you will be sent a response shortly.      </p>
    <p>You will automatically be redirected in a few seconds.</p>
  </div>
 </div>
        <td width="200">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td height="49" bgcolor="#5CA7C2"><p class="Footer">Copyright <strong>© </strong>Fantastic Fuel LLC 2015. All Rights Reserved. Produced as part of Hugh Raynor's IT BTEC.</p></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Too much code.. Try to post only the most relevant bits please..

Comment: not sure it has anything to do with your problem, but did you notice you have two opening `<body>` tags in your HTML ?

Comment: If i understand you correctly, the "thank you" page is the actual problem. Is that correct? If so: have you tried loading this page directly, and does it work then?

Comment: Not sure how or why, but that seemed to resolve it!

Comment: You have form inside form, that isnt good practice. Chrome will chew that but with IE you will have more problems.

Comment: Submitting the form loads a different page so no, the JS on the previous page will no longer be there to run.